# Create object of type ng.IQService; without Injection

Tags: angularjs, typescript

How can I create a local to controller variable of type ng.IQService ( `private _q: ng.IQService;`) without injecting that through the controller?
I am using typescript and angular.
Why I need to do that? I have a legacy code which creates some objects of that controller type inside the controller.

Comment: But if you need it to create legacy controllers (via injection) why not inject it into your controller which can then be used to inject it into the legacy code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> without injecting that through the controller

You can as the `$injector` service for it. Note that every angular app has a *global* `$injector` available as a return from the `bootstrap` function : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

So you can put `$injector` at a global place (like `window`) and then use `$injector.get('$q')` to get a hold of `$q`.